# I'm using swift and I'm getting a error - Expected ',' separator in an if & else statement

Tags: swift, xcode6.1

I've Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d) and I've tried separating it with else and putting double parenthesis but none of it worked.

## For checking all the possibilities the user have. ##
func checkForWin(){
 1. These are all the possibilities.

2. plays = int:int

   ```
   var youWin = 1
   var theyWin = 0
   var whoWon = ["I":0,"you":1]
   for (key,value) in whoWon {
       if ((plays[0] == value && plays[1] == value && plays[2] == value && plays[3] == value)||
       (plays[1] == value && plays[2] == value && plays[3] == value && plays[4] == value)||
       (plays[2] == value && plays[3] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[5] == value)||
       (plays[6] == value && plays[7] == value && plays[8] == value && plays[9] == value)||
       (plays[7] == value && plays[8] == value && plays[9] == value && plays[10] == value)||
       (plays[8] == value && plays[9] == value && plays[10] == value && plays[11] == value)||
       (plays[12] == value && plays[13] == value && plays[14] == value && plays[15] == value)||
       (plays[13] == value && plays[14] == value && plays[15] == value && plays[16] == value)||
       (plays[14] == value && plays[15] == value && plays[16] == value && plays[17] == value)||
       (plays[18] == value && plays[19] == value && plays[20] == value && plays[21] == value)||
       (plays[19] == value && plays[20] == value && plays[21] == value && plays[22] == value)||
       (plays[20] == value && plays[21] == value && plays[22] == value && plays[23] == value)||
       (plays[24] == value && plays[25] == value && plays[26] == value && plays[27] == value)||
       (plays[25] == value && plays[26] == value && plays[27] == value && plays[28] == value)||
       (plays[26] == value && plays[27] == value && plays[28] == value && plays[29] == value)||
       (plays[30] == value && plays[31] == value && plays[32] == value && plays[33] == value)||
       (plays[31] == value && plays[32] == value && plays[33] == value && plays[34] == value)||
       (plays[32] == value && plays[33] == value && plays[34] == value && plays[35] == value)||
       (plays[0] == value && plays[6] == value && plays[12] == value && plays[18] == value)||
       (plays[6] == value && plays[12] == value && plays[18] == value && plays[24] == value)||
       (plays[12] == value && plays[18] == value && plays[24] == value && plays[30] == value)||
       (plays[1] == value && plays[7] == value && plays[13] == value && plays[19] == value)||
       (plays[7] == value && plays[13] == value && plays[19] == value && plays[25] == value)||
       (plays[13] == value && plays[19] == value && plays[25] == value && plays[31] == value)||
       (plays[2] == value && plays[8] == value && plays[14] == value && plays[20] == value)||
       (plays[8] == value && plays[14] == value && plays[20] == value && plays[26] == value)||
       (plays[14] == value && plays[20] == value && plays[26] == value && plays[32] == value)||
       (plays[3] == value && plays[9] == value && plays[15] == value && plays[21] == value)||
       (plays[9] == value && plays[15] == value && plays[21] == value && plays[27] == value)||
       (plays[15] == value && plays[21] == value && plays[27] == value && plays[33] == value)||
       (plays[4] == value && plays[10] == value && plays[16] == value && plays[22] == value)||
       (plays[10] == value && plays[16] == value && plays[22] == value && plays[28] == value)||
       (plays[16] == value && plays[22] == value && plays[28] == value && plays[34] == value)||
       (plays[5] == value && plays[11] == value && plays[17] == value && plays[23] == value)||
       (plays[11] == value && plays[17] == value && plays[23] == value && plays[29] == value)||
       (plays[17] == value && plays[23] == value && plays[29] == value && plays[35] == value)||
       (plays[18] == value && plays[13] == value && plays[8] == value && plays[3] == value)||
       (plays[24] == value && plays[19] == value && plays[14] == value && plays[9] == value)||
       (plays[19] == value && plays[14] == value && plays[9] == value && plays[4] == value)||
       (plays[25] == value && plays[20] == value && plays[15] == value && plays[10] == value)
       (plays[20] == value && plays[15] == value && plays[10] == value && plays[5] == value)||
       (plays[31] == value && plays[26] == value && plays[21] == value && plays[16] == value)||
       (plays[26] == value && plays[21] == value && plays[16] == value && plays[11] == value)||
       (plays[32] == value && plays[27] == value && plays[22] == value && plays[17] == value)||
       (plays[23] == value && plays[16] == value && plays[9] == value && plays[2] == value)||
       (plays[29] == value && plays[22] == value && plays[15] == value && plays[8] == value)||
       (plays[22] == value && plays[15] == value && plays[8] == value && plays[1] == value)||
       (plays[35] == value && plays[28] == value && plays[21] == value && plays[14] == value)||
       (plays[28] == value && plays[21] == value && plays[14] == value && plays[7] == value)||
       (plays[21] == value && plays[14] == value && plays[7] == value && plays[0] == value)||
       (plays[34] == value && plays[27] == value && plays[20] == value && plays[13] == value)||
           (plays[27] == value && plays[20] == value && plays[13] == value && plays[6] == value)){
               userMessage.hidden = false
               userMessage.text = "Looks like \(key) won!"
               resetBtn.hidden = false;
               done = true;
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Sorry guys that "func checkforwin() {" got in the header, its in the code.

Comment: And what is all this stuff supposed to mean? We can't help if we don't know what you're trying to achieve. Also: this kind of code is not maintainable... Please explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Its a condition where it sees where the user plays. All the numbers are the positions of the places where the user the user can play.

Comment: You can describe it as a bigger version of tic tac toe.

Answer (score 2):

check that your enormously hideous condition has a '||' after each sub-clause

tip: look here

```
(plays[25] == value && plays[20] == value && plays[15] == value && plays[10] == value)
```

Comment: Nah didn't work. If I put the ',' then there's another error which pops out - || is not a postfix unary operator.